# Powershell get repadmin /istg in array?

Tags: powershell

Is this possible?

I'm brand new to powershell and am currently in the process of converting a vbscript script to Powershell. The following one-liner command seems to do exactly what the entire vbscript does:

```
Repadmin /istg
```

which outputs

```
Repadmin: running command /istg against full DC ST-DC7.somestuff.com

Gathering topology from site BR-CORP (ST-DC7.somestuff.com):

               Site                ISTG

  ==================   =================

            Portland              ST-DC4

               Venyu              ST-DC5

           BR-Office              ST-DC3

             BR-CORP              ST-DC7
```

The problem is I need to return this info (namely the last 4 lines) as objects which contain a "Site" and "ISTG" field. I tried the following:

```
 $returnValues = Repadmin /istg
 $returnValues
```

But this didin't return anything (possibly because Repadmin writes out the lines instead of actually returning the data?)

Is there a way to get the Info from "Repadmin /istg" into an array?

Comment: try $returnValues = [string](repadmin /istg)

Comment: This does return the info I need, but it's all in a big one-liner string. I could go through and parse it I guess, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way, using regular expressions:

```
$output = repadmin /istg
for ( $n = 10; $n -lt $output.Count; $n++ ) {
  if ( $output[$n] -ne "" ) {
    $output[$n] | select-string '\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*)$' | foreach-object {
      $site = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
      $istg = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    }
    new-object PSObject -property @{
      "Site" = $site
      "ISTG" = $istg
    } | select-object Site,ISTG
  }
}
```

You have to start parsing the 10th item of output and ignore empty lines because `repadmin.exe` seems to insert superflous line breaks (or at least, PowerShell thinks so).

Comment: Better yet for your first line: `$output = repadmin /istg|select -skip 9|?{![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}` That gets only lines with data, and skips the superfluous 9 lines at the start. Actually, at that point you could just include your $_ -match in the ?{} and pipe to a ForEach to create the custom objects right then and there

Comment: Wow that was fast. I've been working towards this solution since I posted but you beat me to it! Thanks!